# Why did they choose a Winnebago to represent Eagle 5?

Tags: spaceballs

I've always wondered as to why [Mel Brooks](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000316/) chose to represent Lone Starr's ship [Eagle 5](https://spaceballs.fandom.com/wiki/Eagle_5) from *Spaceballs* as a 1986 Winnebago and not some other vehicle.

Comment: What some other vehicle would you've expected instead?

Comment: Princess Vespa fly a Mercedes-Benz. What is the uncoolest, unfun, slowest vehicle in total opposition to such luxurious car (that is not utility one)? A mobile.

Answer (score 3):

This could be a nod to the fact, that the Millenium Falcon was a piece of junk. So Mel Brooks made his own version of a piece of junk.

Comment: This is the best explanation, although if you have to explain a joke it becomes less funny.  Another potential parallel, Han Solo and Chewie were smugglers.  Lone Star and Barf could potentially be smugglers as well with the Winnebago having different compartments and all

Comment: And Walt and Jessie cooked meth in one. It's a versatile vehicle.